# Combining solid and dashed format on same line in google line chart

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization

I am using google line chart for my application to display current and projected values. The data I receive would be from database (both current value and projected value). I would like to see solid line till the current score and dashed line for projected score in future. Please let me know how to achieve the this.

Example:

Match : my current expense on 10th may is $5000 and by 7th october it will be $10000 then till $5000, I will have solid line curve and afterword till $10000, I would like to have dashed line.

### Note: This is similar to zones feature in high charts. But I would like to know if the same can be done in google chart.

Comment: Use a _certainty_ [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a *certainty* [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) can be used to cause part of a line to be dashed

---

the values for the *certainty* column should be of type boolean:

`true` --> solid line

`false` --> dashed line

---

see the following working snippet for an example chart...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      new google.visualization.DataTable({
        "cols": [
          {"type": "string", "label": "Year"},
          {"type": "number", "label": "Sales"},
          {"type": "boolean", "role": "certainty"}
        ],
        "rows": [
          {"c": [{"v": "2014"}, {"v": 1000}, {"v": true}]},
          {"c": [{"v": "2015"}, {"v": 1070}, {"v": true}]},
          {"c": [{"v": "2016"}, {"v": 1200}, {"v": true}]},
          {"c": [{"v": "2017"}, {"v": 1070}, {"v": false}]},  // <-- dashed
          {"c": [{"v": "2018"}, {"v": 1200}, {"v": false}]}   // <-- dashed
        ]
      })
    );
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```